# How to generalise two similar arrays in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have two arrays in which just a single parameter is different and other than that complete code is redundant. I want to remove the redundant code and simplify it by generalising the code.

Code :

```
var record1 = ""
var Data1 = {
"@" : {
"Version" : "some"
}
"transation" :{
"payload": {
"@":{}
"#": new Buffer(record1).toString('base64')
}
}
}
var record2 = ""
var Data2 = {
"@" : {
"Version" : "some"
}
"transation" :{
"payload": {
"@":{}
"#": new Buffer(record2).toString('base64')
}
}
}
```

Comment: Write a function that creates the object and accepts the variable part as parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for making a function that accepts the thing(s) that are different and encapsulating the similarities. For example:

```
// create a function
function makeObj(record){
    return {
        "@" : {
            "Version" : "some"
            },
        "transation" :{
            "payload": {
                "@":{},
                "#": new Buffer(record).toString('base64')
            }
        }
    }
} 
// use the function
var Data1 = makeObj(record1)
var Data2 = makeObj(record2)
```